# User authorization via facebook, twitter, gmail and google plus

Tags: android, facebook, gmail

I'm working on an application, and now I need to identify users via facebook, twitter, gmail or google plus account.

I've found a way for Facebook, there is nice SDK and everything is well documented.

Is there some quick way to integrate twitter, gmail and google plus?

I've currently read this: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

But I only get a progress bar that says "Signing in...", and nothing happens...it just stays on screen.

```
 if (!mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
                if (mConnectionResult == null) {
                    mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
                } else {
                    try {
                           mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(PersonalFirstActivity.this,
                                 REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                        // Try connecting again.
                        mConnectionResult = null;
                        mPlusClient.connect();
                    }
                }
             }
```

Also I've noticed this in logcat:

> I/GmsClient(31431): connect: bindService returned false for Intent {
>   act=com.google.android.gms.plus.service.START }

What I'm doing wrong with Google+?

I've registered my app and everything?

I think some code is missing in tutorial after `mConnectionProgressDialog.show();`

Is there a full tutorials for those social networks...I only need sign in procedure, so I can receive first name and second name of the user, maybe email address.

Tnx!